# How to create a 3D Grid of vectors without a memory exception -Unity 3D

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine

Below is a few simple lines of code that is part of uni tech demo. In an attempt to create a 3D grid of vectors within a given area.

My solution thus far is to create a 2D grid at the starting X and Y points and then repeat this process along the Z. 
As a temporary visualization I then instantiate Sphere prefabs.
The purpose of which is to use this grid of vectors as a model for a depth first search path algorithm which I will use to input vectors for a procedurally generated track(currently control points are set manually via editor methods)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GridLayout : MonoBehaviour {
public int GridWidth;
public int GridLength;
public int GridHeight;
public int resolution;

private int ResW;
private int ResL;
private int ResH;
private List<Vector3> GridPoints = new List<Vector3>();
private bool GridCompleted = false;

private GameObject tempObject; 
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    //Area box Start square
    GridPoints.Add(new Vector3(0,0,0)); 
    GridPoints.Add(new Vector3(0,GridHeight,0)); 
    GridPoints.Add(new Vector3(GridWidth,0,0)); 
    GridPoints.Add(new Vector3(GridWidth,GridHeight,0)); 

    ResW = GridWidth/resolution;
    ResH = GridHeight/resolution;
    ResL = GridLength/resolution;
} 

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {



if (GridCompleted == false)
            CreateGrid();

else
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= GridPoints.Count; i++)
    {
            tempObject = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            tempObject.transform.position = GridPoints[i];
    }
}
}   //Area Box End square
//  GridPoints.Add(new Vector3(0,0,GridLength)); 
//  GridPoints.Add(new Vector3(0,GridHeight,GridLength)); 
//  GridPoints.Add(new Vector3(GridWidth,0,GridLength)); 
//  GridPoints.Add(new Vector3(GridWidth,GridHeight,GridLength)); 


void CreateGrid()
{
 if(ResW != GridWidth | ResL != GridLength | ResH != GridHeight)
   {
    for(int l = 1;ResL <= GridLength; l++)
       {
      GridPoints.Add (new Vector3(0,0,ResL));
       ResL = (GridLength/(resolution))*l;

       for(int w = 1;ResW <= GridWidth; w++)
          {
          GridPoints.Add (new Vector3(ResW,0,0));
          ResW = (GridWidth/(resolution))*w;

          for(int h = 1;ResW <= GridHeight; h++)
             {
             GridPoints.Add (new Vector3(0,ResH,0));
             ResH = (GridHeight/(resolution))*h;

             }
         }
    }
 }
    else 
    {
        GridCompleted = true;
    }
```

}

}

Unfortunately this triple for loop leads to a memory exception - this is a high end PC however I will be forced to run my project on a laptop with 4GB ram.

With that in mind : is there a more memory efficient way of creating a vector3 grid.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Typing failure in line

```
for(int h = 1;ResW <= GridHeight; h++)
```

Is causing your memory problems. The most inner loop runs infinitely,  it should be `ResH`. Therefore I suggest to check the for-variable inside the for-statement and not something else:

```
for(int h = 1; h < wharever; h++)
```

secondly: bad code formatting and indentation.
Finally, so far, a `list<object>` is a 1D structure. A 3rd structure would be a `list<list<list<object>>>` or a array `object [][][]`:

```
Vector3 [][][] vector3grid;
vector3grid = new vector3[lenX][][];
for (int x=0; x<lenX; x++)
{
  vector3grid[x] = new vector3 [lenY][];
  for (int y=0; y<lenY; y++)
  {
    vector3grid[x][y] = new vector3 [lenZ];
    // init if needed:
    for(int z=0; ...
      vector3grid[x][y][z] = ...
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
I just noticed that my answer is not 100% correct. The sample above is 1 of 2 (or more) ways to create a 3D array. The easier one of them is following:

In C++/cli:

```
  Array<vector3, 3>^ vector3grid = gcnew array<vector3, 3>(lenX, lenY, lenZ);
```

For c# and VB.net I need to look up the Syntax first.

This is a REAL 3D array now. ;-)

**Edit 2:**
3D in c#:

```
Vector3 [,,] vector3grid = New vector3[lenX,lenY,lenZ];
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I was admittedly inebriated when I wrote this :)

Comment: I fail to see the advantage in using the list method you have depicted however.

Comment: I only gave you an example of a 'jagged' array... An array of an array (of an array). This is a 3D array. I cannot say whether this fits your needs or not.

Comment: Yes, and I appreciated it. My question is if it more toward the efficiently from a memory perspective. As a 1D array works fine.

Comment: If you manage to store 3D data in a 1D array and still know where to look for which value, then I would keep the current solution. If we're talking about the efficiency of the code, there is absolutely no difference as far as I can tell. The advantage from my point of view would be a clearer storage concept...

Comment: Edit 1 to answer. The comment remains valid, no performance difference.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I will try and find an advantage  in your 3D list method with my other works.